# What is the time taken for the ball to reach the window?

Tags: geometry

A ball is projected to a wind 4m high on a vertical wall. The horizontal distance of the ball to the wall is 12m. The ball enters the window at angle of 30 degree to the horizontal. Find the time taken to reach the window.

I have worked it as 4.0 s , the book says t = 0.7 s , I am thinking this is too small!

Is the angle of projection 60 by geometry?
If I know it is or not I will complete this.

Comment: How did you find the time as $4.0$ seconds?

Comment: I used both  vertical and horizontal components of motions, i was using 60 degrees , i have realized my mistake, should be 30 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Use the distance equations for both vertical and horizontal directions,

$$12=v_x t$$
$$4 = v_y t - \frac 12 g t^2$$

Combine them to get

$$ \frac{v_y}{v_x} =  \frac{ 4+\frac 12 g t^2}{12}$$

From the 30 degree projection angle,

$$ \frac{v_y}{v_x} = \tan 30$$

Then, we have

$$\tan 30 = \frac{ 4+\frac 12 g t^2}{12}$$

Solve for the time

$$t= \sqrt{\frac{2(12\tan 30 - 4)}{g} }=0.77s$$

Comment: agreed but is it best to assume  angle of projection is 30 degrees why is it?

Comment: It is the angle to the horizontal for the projectile to enter the window. For different projection angles, the time taken to reach the window would be different